# Rugarch external regressors in mean/variance

Tags: r, volatility

What is the proper formatting of the variable provided to external.regressors = ..?
My data looks like this:

```
           regressor     dependent
2008-01-04         3  0.0243990059
2008-01-08         3  0.0057341705
2008-01-09         3  0.0047333058
2008-01-10         3  0.0003631741
2008-01-11         3 -0.0019384547
2008-01-14         3 -0.0016992358
```

I am using the Rugarch package to estimate an ARMA(2,0)-GARCH(1,1) process with an external regressor in both the mean and varince.
As (of course) I am dealing with the Time series, my data is formatted as zoo.

If I provide the zoo variable as here:

```
garch.spec <- ugarchspec(
  variance.model = list(model="sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1), 
external.regressors = regressor),
  mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(2, 0), include.mean = TRUE),
)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in modelinc[15] <- dim(variance.model$external.regressors)[2] : 
  replacement has length zero
```

If I, instead specify the regressors as **external.regressors = as.matrix(coredata(regressor))**
The error doesn't show up and I am able to estimate the model with

```
ugarchfit(garch.spec, dependent)
```

Where *dependent* is a zoo variable. The results, however, don't make sense.

I believe I don't get how the datatypes work here. I believe garch should be able to work with zoo files and have read the package description but did not find anything helpful. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `?ugarchspec` we find

> external.regressors - A **matrix** object containing the external
>   regressors to include in the variance equation with as many rows as
>   will be included in the data (which is passed in the fit function).

So, if `df` contains your example data, using

```
garch.spec <- ugarchspec(
  variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1), external.regressors = matrix(df$regressor)),
  mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(2, 0), include.mean = TRUE))
ugarchfit(garch.spec, df$dependent)
```

works. That is the correct usage of `external.regressors` and questions on how satisfactory the results are most likely are related to methodology and more suitable for [Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks, I get it. I was confused because call to ugarchfit allows zoo variables as an input. The second part of my question was indeed for Stats.SE